# How to pass some custom parameters to SendCompleted event in Mailkit.smtp?

Tags: mailkit

How to pass some custom parameters to SendCompleted event in Mailkit.SmtpClient?
I expect something like in System.Net.Mail that I can easily pass some custom parameters and doing some process inside the SendCompleted event.

need advice

thanks a lot
Don

Comment: How do you do this for System.Net.Mail?

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this:

in System.Net.Mail I use below:

```
        client.SendCompleted += (s, e) =>
        {
            Client_SendCompleted(s, e);
           ...
           ...
        };

private static void Client_SendCompleted(object s, AsyncCompletedEventArgs e)
```

in Mailkit I use below:

```
smtp.MessageSent += (sender, args) => Smtp_MessageSent(sender, args, _jo);
```

_jo is my JObject

```
 private static void Smtp_MessageSent(object sender,   MailKit.MessageSentEventArgs e, JObject _jo)
```